# Drag and drop issue in Qt: Pass parameter to receiving dropEvent

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

A `healthPackButton` is dropped on a `mysquare`. Now I would like to add a value to this button (because I have a number of healthPackButtons and I want to be able to differentiate them). I have tried changing the makeDrag function for it to accept an extra parameter but than my SIGNAL was no longer matched.

**Question**: How can I pass additional information (=> int value) to my dropEvent handler inside another class.

`Dialog` class

```
    for (int i=0; i<healthPks.size(); i++){
        int value = healthPks.at(i);
        QPushButton *healthPackButton = new QPushButton(title,this);
        connect(healthPackButton,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(makeDrag()));
    }



    void Dialog::makeDrag(){
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData;
        mime->setText("This is a test");
        drag->setMimeData(mime);
        drag->start();
    }
```

`mysquare` class

```
void MySquare::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event){
    isHealthPack=true;
    int xCoord = curX/width;
    int yCoord = curY/height;
    int value = 0; //what's the value??
    const QMimeData *mimeData = event->mimeData();
    emit healthMapChanged(xCoord,yCoord,value);
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an additional parameter into your slot, you can use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsignalmapper.html) – the documentation has an example of adding a `QString const&` parameter, but you can use an `int` in exactly the same way to pass the value to a `makeDrag(int)`.

You could then use `QMimeType`'s [`setData`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmimedata.html#setData) (converting your `int` to a `QByteArray` using [`QByteArray::number`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qbytearray.html#number) for example) to get that value to the drop target.

Comment: what kind of mime type should I use? text/plain?

Comment: text/plain if you pass it as text. Some generic binary type if you pass it as I said above (`application/octet-stream` or whatever it's called).

Comment: The example doesn't make this clear but can I send multiple data? Because I would like to send a pointer to the button also so I can disable it when it's dropped.

Comment: _A single QMimeData object can store the same data using several different formats at the same time._ - the Qt docs are really good, but they need to be read to be appreciated :)

Comment: Yes thanks but I meant the QSignalMapper not the QMimeData. I would like to send a pointer (of the button) to the makeDrag() so I can disable that button.

Comment: _This class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal._ Either/Or. Only one at a time.